# excel filter function using of array criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel

My problem is that I need to show an array filtered in specific columns in my excel without copy past result cell by cell.

Simples example:

**I have 2 arrays:**
invoices_nr# with x rows and 3 columns depending on input
select_prj# title row showing where the result should get shown

**I tried:**
FILTER(invoices_nr#;ISNUMBER(MATCH(select_prj#;INDEX(invoices_nr#;;3);0)))
and
=FILTER(invoices_nr#;IFERROR(SEARCH(select_prj#;INDEX(invoices_nr#;;3));0)>0)
and of course
=FILTER(invoices_nr#;INDEX(invoices_nr#;;3)=select_prj#)

if select_prj# would be only one value all of them should work; but as soon I use an array it will not;

Does anyone have a solution out of it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am showing result always with dynamic arrays. Adding sum result to the range with VStack is quite simple using SUMIFS; but as soon I need to add text  data using filter it get impossible to me.
Untill now I simple copy paste c2 x times until ax2 to get text correct addressed; goal is to have only one formular ..
e.g.:
result row showing     product1,product2;product3,...
      my array content have only details of product1, produc3,..
              hence I wanted to use filter function with need to get result shown in proper result column 
I hope my question is now clear
Thanks